# False "Sequence contains no elements" exception when using Single()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I seem to be having an issue with a false exception thrown when using `.Single()` in a Linq statement.  Checking the debugger I found that my list does contain the element I am looking for and the id field matches.  The code that throws the exception is

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    FilterQueue filterqueue = db.FilterQueues.Single(f => f.FilterQueueId == id);

    if (filterqueue == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(filterqueue);
}
```

However, switching to a more verbose coding style works. Like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    FilterQueue filterqueue = null;
    foreach (var f in db.FilterQueues)
    {
        if (f.FilterQueueId == id) filterqueue = f;
    }
    if (filterqueue == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(filterqueue);
}
```

Funnily enough, if I let the code just run past the exception, it does grab the correct item to display the details of.

Now, of course, I can switch the Single to SingleOrDefault and that works fine; However, since the first code block is what is written automatically by the framework, I want to understand what I am doing wrong.  If I am making a systematic mistake, I would like to correct it the right way.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework and what is the type of the FilterQueueId?

Comment: I am using the Entity Framework, and FilterQueueId is an int in the code as well as the primary key in the database.

Comment: If you are using EF6 you can try logging your queries as described here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx .

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `SingleOrDefault()`.

In your code, you are checking for `null`, when `null` could never be the result of Single();

Here's what you want:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    FilterQueue filterqueue = db.FilterQueues.SingleOrDefault(f => f.FilterQueueId == id);

    if (filterqueue == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(filterqueue);
}
```

Comment: I believe you missed my last paragraph.  I did say i could use SingleOrDefault and that is actually what I chose to do to workaround the issue.  However, the code as presented is what the framework wrote for me when I had it add the controller.  I wanted to know A) Why I was getting bogus code and B) more importantly, when I checked the values I had a single response.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, `Single` would never return `null`, If there are no matching elements found then it would throw an exception.

> "Sequence contains no element"

You need [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which would return `null` if no element is found.

Your second code block which is using the loop is not an equivalent representation of `Single`. `Enumerable.Single` will throw the exception if more than one elements are returned matching the criteria. Your loop, however is returning the last matched item. There could be multiple items in the list but you will never know about it. Your loop is more similar to `LastOrDefault`

```
foreach (var f in db.FilterQueues)
{
    if (f.FilterQueueId == id) filterqueue = f;
}
```

Comment: Given the naming of the variable I suspect that the OP actual needs a LinqToEntities solution rather than a LinqToObject solution.

Comment: Yes but the `foreach` would enumerate the whole database locally.

Comment: @Aron, I am not saying to use `foreach`, I am just trying to explain that the code snippet would not behave same as `Single`

Comment: My last paragraph mentioned my knowledge of the SingleOrDefault.  The correct code was not the issue.  The issue is that the frameowrk is giving me bogus code when I added the controller, AND more importantly, the Linq statement should not be throwing that error as evidence by the second block of code.  (Yes, i know it would give me the last one, but it still gives me one.  More than one would have been another error)

Comment: @Xitch13, I have no idea why you are getting that auto generate code *or even how*, but profile your SQL Server to see what query is being generated for Single.